# NextJs - Close Window or Close Tab

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In Nextjs / Reactjs,
[image]

the top image in the red box is how to find out if the user clicks the close tab or close window button, how do I do that? I've tried looking for references but it doesn't work, maybe there are other references,

because I want to add a function if the user clicks close tab or window then the action hits the existing api

Answer (score 0):

if your env in the browser,you can watch event beforeunload

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
 // do something
});
```

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/javascript-detect-browser-tab-close-840a44c82d17

##### your can run this code test event,but if you want to do asynchronous operations when the page is closed, there is a high probability of failure

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', ev => {
    debugger
    localStorage.setItem(Math.random(), Math.random())
  })
  window.addEventListener('unload', ev => {
    debugger
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: i try this code : 

 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        keycloak.clearToken();
      });
    }
  });, still not working